# Scrapy LinkExtractor joining urls that cause 404

Tags: python, url, scrapy

I'm working with a site crawler that finds 404 links.

Im now encountering errors not due to the urls found on the site but due to the automated merging of the linkextractor. how do I do this?

```
    def parse_links(self, response):
        if response.meta.get('is_image') is None or not response.meta.get('is_image'):
            link_extractor_url = LxmlLinkExtractor(unique = True, process_value=self.process_value)
            links = link_extractor_url.extract_links(response)
            if response.status == 200:
                for img in response.css('img'):
                    image_here = img.css('::attr(src)').extract_first()
                    yield scrapy.Request(image_here, callback = self.parse_links, meta={'is_image':True})
                for link in links:
                    if link.url not in self.visited_urls:
                        yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback = self.parse_links, meta={'is_image':False})
            else:
                item = LinkcheckerItem()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['status'] = response.status
                item['link_type'] = 'local'
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer',None)
                yield item
        else:
            if response.status !=200:
                item = LinkcheckerItem
                item['no'] = self.no_url
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['status'] = response.status
                item['link_type'] = 'local'
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer',None)
                yield item
```

heres my code for parse links with the link extractor. 
it crawls successfully on most parts the website but on a few it returns the wrong urls.

**referer url:**

https://********.com/foo/floop/stoop/?lref=pb_action_pg

**URL FROM LINK ON WEBSITE:**

https://********.com/foo/floop/stoo/?lref=pb_stoop_pg

**URL GENERATED BY LINKEXTRACTOR**

https://********.com/stoo/?lref=pb_stoop_pg&ldest=gp

it seems to have removed the '/foo/floop' part of my url

or can someone atleast enlighten me on the behavior of scrapy's linkextractor?

Comment: What's the content of your `process_value` method?

Comment: I haven't applied anything to it yet. so its basically just 

`def(self,value): return value`

Comment: I think we would need to actually test the LinkExtractor or see how is the html code of that page to advise you something else, but I would guess that those urls aren't relative and when using the `response.urljoin` the `/foo/floop` gets removed, you could always get the `href` using some xpath and then build the urls with the correct path.